# installation of twisted fails using python3 on centos 6.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos, twisted

1. First, i compiled and installed python3.3 manually, no error reported.

   ```
   cd /path/to/python3.3
   ./configure
   make && make install
   ```
2. Then i downloaded twisted source tree and install it with these commands:

   ```
   cd /path/to/twisted
   python3 setup.py install
   ```
3. then the error reported:

   ```
   error: in 'ext_modules' option (extension 'twisted.runner.portmap'), 'sources' must be present and must be a list of source filenames
   ```

   I would very appreciate any help getting twisted to work with python3 on centos.

   Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't install Twisted on Python 3 this way.  Check the source out from subversion:

```
svn checkout svn://svn.twistedmatrix.com/svn/Twisted/tags/releases/twisted-13.1.0
```

Then run setup3.py:

```
python3.3 setup3.py install
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but the problem is some module can't be improted, such as the error: `ImportError: No module named 'twisted.python.systemd'`. 

BTW:
Everything works fine on my ubuntu, why centos didn't. This makes me very confused.

Comment: Twisted for Python 3 is still on progress: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/milestone/Python-3.x